# related to float and width

Tags: html, css

I have a sidebar and a content area. I just floated the sidebar to the left and the content area to the right. But I have problem when the screen size changes. There occurs a significant space between the two floats. I think it's due to the size of the image in the content area and since it's floated right. Hence I floated this content area also to the left. now the content area is not extending to the extreme right end of the screen. Is there any way to put the content area fit in the right portion without any space (just the space to divide the sidebar and content area is enough)?

If you need more explanations, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide the HTML that you're working with. Use JSFiddle.net to show a working demo

Comment: please post your code here.........

Comment: this is the site: http://jilson.me/stack/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your CSS to this:

```
.dashContent {
     float: left;
     margin: 10px;
     position: relative;
     top: 25px;
     min-width: 80%;
}

.sidebarDash {
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 195px;
}
```

<strike>This will remove the space and also retain fluidity in the layout</strike> - Removed as the OP wants a fixed layout

Comment: That will be a problem. Using mixed layouts is tricky since you will then get overlap at some screen size. Is this layout designed for a minimum screensize? (Desktops/Laptops only)

Comment: If it is designed for a specific minimum resolution, when you say the screen-size changes, what is the change you are testing against?

Comment: I mean the minimum screen size is 1024x768

Comment: I understand. I'm just a little confused what the issue you are facing is. Can you provide screenshots? (Also try with the CSS I provided above and see if that helps)

Comment: Please modify your CSS to use the one I've presented above.

Comment: 1024px (Max Width) - 195px (Sidebar width you have currently set) - 10px (Margin Width)

Comment: 1024 is the minimum width. Not the maximum

Comment: Okay. Final edit. This should do...
If not, I suggest we take it over to chat instead of a back and forth here...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17737/discussion-between-user1012181-and-aj)

Answer (score 1):

Place `.sidebarDash` with `adsolute position` and give `padding-left` the same as sidebar width to `.dashContent`

Wrap these two in one main DIV as -

```
<div class="dashContainer">

  <div class="sidebarDash"></div>
  <div class="dashContent"></div>

</div> <!-- Clears the float with CSS -->
```

CSS -

```
.dashContainer{ overflow: hidden; position: relative }
.sidebarDash { position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 200px; }
.dashContent { padding: 0 0 0 210px; }
```

jQuery -

Insert this in `<head>` section of the document -

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function(){
    var sidebarHeight = $('.sidebarDash').height(); 
    $('.dashContainer').css('min-height', sidebarHeight);
  })
</script>
```

Comment: But I cannot use a fixed width for the content area. It should be flexible depending on the screensize!

Comment: Here, it increases the sidebar size also when the screen size changes!

Comment: No, I mean, when the screen size changes, it also increases the size of the sidebar. But it should be fixed width with flexible content area

Comment: yes, it worked. But some content at the bottom is getting hidden. Or going over the footer!

Comment: Sorry to ask, where should I apply this?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using float:right use float:left so both divs stay together, have a look on this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/FZZnk/

Let me know if this solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to use percent to all of the divs width.
second, you can make the both float to the same side (right or left), and use margin or padding in percent to make to space between these divs.

```
.dashContainer{ overflow: hidden; width: 100%; }
.sidebarDash { float: left; width: 20%; }
.dashContent { float: left; width: 80%; }
```

Now, because your left side bar has a fix width and float left, you can do this:
remove the float right, and add margin-left at the size of your side bar.
and don't forget to set the div to width: 100%.

```
.dashContent {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100%; }
```

Comment: I understand, use this: .dashContent {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 210px;
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    width: 100%; }